# Playing sound effect just before AVAudioRecorder

Tags: ios, core-audio, nsthread, avaudiorecorder

I am recording audio with `AVAudioRecorder`. I want to however play a short sound before the recording starts. I am doing this with `AudioServicesCreatSystemSoundId`. I notice that I need to pause the thread after calling the sound effect or else it will start playing, then get interrupted by the `AVAudioRecord` `record` call and then finish playing after the recording has been stoped again.

So I have something like this:

```
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef) pathURL, &audioEffect);
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(audioEffect);
[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.7];
[_audioRecorder record];
```

The problem is that one notices the delay. I know there are apps out there (like i.e. Voxer) that make the sound without delaying the actual recording. I tried splitting of the first two lines in a block, but that didn't help. How do they do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For low latency (no noticeable start delay) audio recording, use a pre-started RemoteIO Audio Unit instead of the AVAudioRecorder API.